# PC is on but light not flashing; Computer hangs

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I've got a Compaq Deskpro desktop that boots, but the power light isn't flashing and the computer locks up.  I can't even run the media player or shutdown the computer.  Help me please.

Comment: Posting the exact model of the PC and the amount of memory installed will help others help you with troubleshooting. Am I correct in understanding it boots into windows fine, but becomes unresponsive shortly after getting to the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform system restore first in safe mode and check if system locks up in safe mode as well or not. IF its locks up unplug all the external devices and try system restore. Do you get any error message when you try to open media player. Try to open the side panel of the tower unit and check if all the connections are fine on motherboard for front LED.

Answer (score 0):

[Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) a live CD and burn it to a CD, and then try to boot the computer off of that.  If your computer boots up and lets you get to a desktop, but then freezes shortly thereafter, see if the same issue occurs when using the live CD.  If so, then the issue is almost certainly hardware.  If not, then the issue is probably with the OS.

If it's the OS, your best bet is a reinstall after backing up files, but comment back if you have a reason to want to avoid a reinstall.

If it's hardware, first try what dreamerboy mentioned.  You should also try to rule out the two most likely issues, overheating and memory.  If you have multiple memory sticks, try to take them all out except for one, and cycle through until you start the computer without any issues.  For the overheating, try to open up the case and leave a fan blowing on it to see if you can run the computer for longer without the issue.